# Customer not getting logged in after updating catalog price rule

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, login, catalog-price-rules

I am having a strange problem . If i update catalog price rule then on front end i can't get logged in . Page keeps on loading and after some time it shows 500 error .
If i update that customer account from backend just editing and saving , it enables me to log in from front .
Any idea what am i doing wrong ?

I have followed the code to see which lines are putting it in endless loop. I found that following lines in Mage/Sales/Model/Quote in _afterLoad function are causing this loop.

```
if (1 == $this->getData('trigger_recollect')) {

           $this->collectTotals()->save();

        }
```

If I comment out `$this->collectTotals()->save();` it loads fine.

After reading more on forums it says that when we update catalog rules in admin, then magento set this trigger to 1 so that it calculate totals again on front end and that puts in loop as it gets too long. Like suggested on these

```
http://www.techytalk.info/catalog-price-rules-not-applied-creating-order-magento-admin/
```

and here

```
https://github.com/magespecialist/MSP_CashOnDelivery/issues/6
```

Can you suggest what can be the proper solution, commenting this line will have other effects as well I would think, although it currently seems to work fine.
Thanks for looking into this

Comment: In case of `500` error, please check your Magento & Server log files. It will help you to identify real problem.

Comment: this is what i am getting on redis_session.log file . 'EMERG (0): sip3-156.nexcess.net|18311: Unable to connect to Redis; falling back to MySQL handler' .

Comment: I haven't experienced with `redis`, but I'm sure its related to that. Try to disabled `Redis` and see its work or not

Comment: and on exception.log file : ..../app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('loginPost')

Comment: Can you please add `exception stack trace`  of `exception.log` file in your question

Comment: I have followed the code to see which lines are putting it in endless loop. I found that following lines in Mage/Sales/Model/Quote in _afterLoad function are causing this loop.
 

    if (1 == $this->getData('trigger_recollect')) {
       
               $this->collectTotals()->save();
       
            }

If I comment out `$this->collectTotals()->save();` it loads fine.

Comment: After reading more on forums it says that when we update catalog rules in admin, then magento set this trigger to 1 so that it calculate totals again on front end and that puts in loop as it gets too long. Like suggested on these 
 

    http://www.techytalk.info/catalog-price-rules-not-applied-creating-order-magento-admin/

and here 

    https://github.com/magespecialist/MSP_CashOnDelivery/issues/6

Can you suggest what can be the proper solution, commenting this line will have other effects as well I would think, although it currently seems to work fine.
Thanks for looking into this

Answer (score 0):

You have a redis session management issue.

Double check your `local.xml`, you probably have some mistake.

Try also disabling redis sessions and falling back to MySQL to see if it fix.

Comment: i disabled redis but still same issue .

Comment: So they are not related... any custom module installed that can interact with customer model?

Comment: I have followed the code to see which lines are putting it in endless loop. I found that following lines in Mage/Sales/Model/Quote in _afterLoad function are causing this loop.
 

    if (1 == $this->getData('trigger_recollect')) {
       
               $this->collectTotals()->save();
       
            }

If I comment out `$this->collectTotals()->save();` it loads fine.

Comment: After reading more on forums it says that when we update catalog rules in admin, then magento set this trigger to 1 so that it calculate totals again on front end and that puts in loop as it gets too long. Like suggested on these 
 

    http://www.techytalk.info/catalog-price-rules-not-applied-creating-order-magento-admin/

and here 

    https://github.com/magespecialist/MSP_CashOnDelivery/issues/6

Can you suggest what can be the proper solution, commenting this line will have other effects as well I would think, although it currently seems to work fine.
Thanks for looking into this

Comment: You could have the totals not correctly updated after some cart change (insert/remove) products. Make sure it is correctly working.